# Javascript, how to transform array row to object fields

Tags: javascript, transformation

I need to transform this structure:

```
[
{"Field1": "value11", "Field2":"value21", "CField1":[{"Id": 1, "Value":"myValue11", "Flag":"Y"}, {"Id": 2, "Value":"myValue12", "Flag":"n"}]},
{"Field1": "value21", "Field2":"value22", "CField1":[{"Id": 1, "Value":"myValue21", "Flag":"Y"}, {"Id": 2, "Value":"myValue22", "Flag":"n"}]}
]
```

to

```
[
{"Field1": "value11", "Field2":"value12", "Value1": "myValue11", "Flag1":"Y", "Value2": "myValue12", "Flag2":"n"},
{"Field1": "value21", "Field2":"value21", "Value1": "myValue21", "Flag1":"Y", "Value2": "myValue22", "Flag2":"n"},
]
```

i found that similar solution:

```
tab.forEach(function (item) {
  transformedObject[item.key] = transformedObject[item.key] ? `${transformedObject[item.key]}, ${item.value}` : item.value;
});

console.log(transformedObject);

// Access the '2' property
console.log(transformedObject['2']);
```

but need some help to adapt it to my case

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map the inner array as new objects.

```js
const
    data = [{ Field1: "value11", Field2: "value21", CField1: [{ Id: 1, Value: "myValue11", Flag: "Y" }, { Id: 2, Value: "myValue12", Flag: "n" }] }, { Field1: "value21", Field2: "value22", CField1: [{ Id: 1, Value: "myValue21", Flag: "Y" }, { Id: 2, Value: "myValue22", Flag: "n" }] }],
    result = data.map(({ CField1, ...o }) => Object.assign(
        o,
        ...CField1.map(({ Id, ...q }, i) => Object.fromEntries(Object
            .entries(q)
            .map(([k, v]) => [k + (i + 1), v])
        ))
    ));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: in perfomance can be better than: ratings.forEach((element, index, array) => {
 element.CField1.forEach((nuovo) => {
   element['Value' + nuovo.Id] = nuovo.Value;
    element['Flag' + nuovo.Id] = nuovo.Flag;
  });
});

Comment: you mutate `element`and this contains still `CField1`.

Comment: correct, i can remove it. not sure about which can be faster

Comment: how many items do you have?

Comment: up to some thousands

Answer (score 0):

You can map your data like this:

```js
data = [
{"Field1": "value11", "Field2":"value21", "CField1":[{"Id": 1, "Value":"myValue11", "Flag":"Y"}, {"Id": 2, "Value":"myValue12", "Flag":"n"}]},
{"Field1": "value21", "Field2":"value22", "CField1":[{"Id": 1, "Value":"myValue21", "Flag":"Y"}, {"Id": 2, "Value":"myValue22", "Flag":"n"}]}
]

console.log(data.map(function(value, key) {
  return Object.entries(value).reduce(function(carry, [ key, value ]) {
    if (key !== 'CField1') {
      carry[key] = value
    } else {
      carry = Object.assign(carry, value.reduce(function(innerCarry, value, key) {
         innerCarry[`Flag${value.Id}`] = value.Flag
         innerCarry[`Value${value.Id}`] = value.Value
         return innerCarry;
      }, {}))
    }
    return carry
  }, {})
}))
```